# Delphi RegEX library and unicode characters

Tags: regex, delphi

If one uses `\b` for a word boundary, it seems it understands only ASCII alphabet
for example the pattern

`\bM\b` will match `aaaa M bbbbbb`

but if I have

```
aaaaa Mädchen
```

it will too, because it considers `ä` to be an end of word.

Are there any flags to set for this regexp lib to accept Unicode strings too?
It seems very unlikely that this lib would be so primitive but it is not in the options

```
TRegExOption = (roNone, roIgnoreCase, roMultiLine, roExplicitCapture,
roCompiled, roSingleLine, roIgnorePatternSpace);
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282749/best-delphi-regex-library) can help you.

Comment: [TRegExpr](http://www.regexpstudio.com/tregexpr/tregexpr.html) claims to have unicode support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), Delphi regex lib is based on PCRE and the predefined character class `\w` in PCRE is only ASCII based, therefore `\b` is also only ASCII based.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is very sad indeed Delphi is priding itself of unicode features, international etc and they a have a regex engine just for the US, PATHETIC

Comment: PCRE have an option PCRE_UCP that enables Unicode support for \B, \b, \D, \d, \S, \s, \W, \w https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22372

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookaround to make your own word boundaries to fit your preferred definition of a "word".  E.g. if you want to match "M" as a word and treat all Unicode letters, numbers and marks as word characters, use:

```
(?<![\pL\pN\pM])M(?![\pL\pN\pM])
```