# regex - find multiline string that does not contain substring

Tags: regex, parsing, delphi, regex-lookarounds

I need to find certain chunks of code that are missing the `raise` keyword as follows:

These are the types of matches that I'm searching for

```
except
  FreeAndNil(result);
end;
```

While these should be **ignored**:

```
except
  FreeAndNil(result);
  raise;
end;
```

Bear in mind that between the `except` and `end;` keywords there may be any type or length of text.

I tried the following regex expression: `except((?!raise).)*end;` however it does not work on a multiline scenario.

Comment: If there is an option to make the dot match a newline you could use your pattern https://regex101.com/r/puLnO6/1 or perhaps with an inline modifier `(?s)except((?!raise).)*end;` or `except((?!raise)[\s\S])*end;`

Comment: You could also match the newlines instead `except\s*\n(?:(?![\t ]*\b(?:except|raise;)$).*\n)*end;` https://regex101.com/r/Wx2bGx/1

Comment: I like the idea of the 4th bird. Is delphi using PCRE? If so, you can even use somewhat with [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) like this one: [`except\s*(?:\n.*)*?(?:\n\s*(?:end|raise(*SKIP)(*F));)`](https://regex101.com/r/DLNGKZ/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208789/delphi-regex-library-and-unicode-characters) so I think it does, not really sure though as I have no experience with delphi. That is a nice pattern you suggested, even less steps.

Comment: @bobblebubble I think you might even shorten it to [except\s*(?:\R.*)*?\R\s*(?:end|raise(*SKIP)(*F));](https://regex101.com/r/WJwnsh/1) You should post it as well if it supports PCRE :)

Comment: As suggested by @Thefourthbird I ended up using `except((?!raise)[\s\S])*end;` as it matched the requirements I needed. Thank you very much for your sugestions.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Indeed! dunno why I put that around! thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option matching the newlines could be matching all the lines between except and end by using a negative lookahead asserting that those lines do not start with either of except or end:

```
\bexcept\s*\r?\n(?:(?!(?:except|[\t ]+raise;)$).*\r?\n)*end;
```

In parts

- `\bexcept\s*\r?\n` Match except, 0+ whitespace chars and a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `(?:except|[\t ]+raise;)$)` Match either `except` or 1+ spaces or tabs and `raise;` followed by the end of the string.
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `.*\r?\n` Match the whole line followed by a newline
- `)*` Repeat the non capturing group 0+ times
- `end;` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYf47d/1)